# Tableview and custom cells unpredictable behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a tableview controller with custom cells. For each type of cell, I created a prototype cell in the storyboard as well as a class.

Here's one of the cells:

[image]

The cell has a circular button that contains a number.

I'm trying to modify the value of the number in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
         TrackMilstoneCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrackMilstoneCell"];
         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[TrackMilstoneCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TrackMilstoneCell"];
         }
         cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
         cell.milestoneNumber.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xA875E1);
         [cell.milestoneNumber.titleLabel setText:@"2"];

         return cell;
     } ...
```

However, I'm getting a very unpredictable behavior. Every time the tableview is reloaded I sometimes get 1 (the default in storyboard), and sometimes 2 (which is what i want).

[image]

This is the code for my (TrackMilstoneCell) class:

```
#import "TrackMilstoneCell.h"

@implementation TrackMilstoneCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self viewSetup];
}

-(void)viewSetup
{

    self.milestoneNumber.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.milestoneNumber.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.milestoneNumber.layer.borderWidth = 4;
    self.milestoneNumber.layer.cornerRadius = self.milestoneNumber.bounds.size.width / 2.0;

}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}



@end
```

Comment: That is because of reusing the cell, you need to add complete  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Where is the else part of cellForRowAtIndexPath? Are you sure the row number is 0 for that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kaushal's suggestion did the trick!

Instead of setting the title like this:

```
[cell.milestoneNumber.titleLabel setText:@"2"]
```

I did:

```
[cell.milestoneNumber setTitle:@"2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And now it's working just fine. Though I'm not sure why exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with reusability, so here the best solution is reset the label in prepareForReuse method like this:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];
  [self.milestoneNumber setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

And while configuring the cell, set title like:

```
[self.milestoneNumber setTitle:@"2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: update button text using :  self.milestoneNumber.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;   [button setTitle:@"2"forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set default stage of your button in awakeFromNib.
In your custom table view cell class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.milestoneNumber.titleLabel.text = @"";
}
```